# After deleting a module : "Setup version for module 'xxx' is not specified"

Tags: magento2, module, setup

I was learning Magento 2 by creating a simple module, and after I deleted all files I'm getting this error. I removed the row from `setup_module` in DB and reindexed, but I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mate, Hope you have deleted from `app/code/` and `setup_module` table.

But the entry still exists in the `app/etc/config.php` file.

So, best way is to run following command again

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Then

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Best of Luck!

Comment: You welcome @Tom! (Y)

Answer (score 1):

Deleting module does not effect , If you do not want to use then disable the module by executing command in command line,

`php bin/magento module:disable Vendor_Modulename`

Just replace with `Vendor_Modulename` with your module and vendor name

Comment: Or remove entry from `app/etc/config.php`